# PHP MYSQLI WHILE check for record to determine if invalid id or password

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I'm not so much having a problem and got this method to work but was wondering if anyone would have a better method or more logical method to handle a invalid id by checking the while statement instead of having to create a variable then check it. Or any other suggestion. Thank you.

```
<?php
session_start();
/**
 * Created by Steven K - KoelTech.net
 * User: Steve
 * Date: 10/30/2016
 * Time: 5:48 PM
 */
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//TODO Login Check Method
$mysqli = new mysqli("****", "****", "**", "****");
if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
    // Check if database connects
    die('Unable to connect to the database');
}
//
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT username, email, firstname, lastname,  active, password FROM members WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();

$iscorrectid = false;
$result = $stmt->get_result();
//If Found run code else nothing!
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $iscorrectid = true;
    if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION["firstname"] = $row['firstname'];
        $_SESSION["lastname"] = $row['lastname'];
        $_SESSION["active"] = $row['active'];
        //User Logged In So Redirect To Memeber Home Page
        header( 'Location: http://fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com/members/index.php' ) ;
    } else
    { // LOGIN FAILED(Wrong Password)
            header( 'Location: http://fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com/login.php?invalid=1' );
    }
}
//check if invalid id
if(!$iscorrectid){
    header( 'Location: http://fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com/login.php?invalid=1' );
}

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: don't need loop .try something like this SELECT username, email, firstname, lastname,  active, password FROM members WHERE username = ? password=? pass the username and password both in query if more than one 0 row affected is valid memeber otherwise invalid member

Comment: why need that last most execute statement ?

Comment: was part of a demonstration was thinking same thing but did adjust to just use the IF statement thank you much!

Comment: i think you need more clarification which one is incorrect either username or password is it ?

Comment: Did adjust to just use the IF statement thank you much! i assume i cant use password  ? as its a bcrypt with opt 10 and random salt . Best method so far i've heard based on cpu usage for the server i use for encryption.

IF (ID || password) redirect, is fine for me. as i wouldn't want the user to know

Comment: did you got solution ?

Comment: yes i did thank you JYoThl thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127025/discussion-between-jyothi-and-steven-casanova).

Answer (score 0):

Was over thinking it thanks, JYoThI

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc() ;
    if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION["firstname"] = $row['firstname'];
        $_SESSION["lastname"] = $row['lastname'];
        $_SESSION["active"] = $row['active'];
        //User Logged In So Redirect To Member Home Page
        header( 'Location: http://fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com/members/index.php' ) ;
    }
    else
    { // LOGIN FAILED INCORRECT ID OR PASSWORD
        header( 'Location:      http://fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com/login.php?invalid=1' );
    }
```

Comment: glad to help you . go ahead